# Assembler for the HACK assembly language

Tags: beginner, c

Here's my assembler for the HACK assembly language, part of the [Nand2Tetris course](http://www.nand2tetris.org). I'd really appreciate any comments/criticism/help!

If you want to know what input and output files should look like, you can check out the test data in the /tests/ folder on [GitHub](https://github.com/matTthewbyrd/Nand2Tetris/tree/master/06/asm).

**Assembler.c:**

```
/**
 *  file: assembler.c
 *
 *  usage of assembler for the hack assembly language.
 *
 */

#include "assemble.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check input is correct
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: assembler source output\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open source file
    FILE* source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (source == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open source file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE* output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open output file %s\n", argv[2]);
        fclose(source);
        return 1;
    }

    if (assemble(source, output) == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Quitting with error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Assemble.h:**

```
/**
 *  file: assemble.h
 *
 *  assembler for the hack assembly language.
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_A 32767
#define COMP_TABLE_SIZE 28
#define JUMP_TABLE_SIZE 7
#define MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE 10

// node for symbol and its translation
typedef struct symNode
{
    char symbol[MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE];
    char translation[17];
    struct symNode* next;
}
symNode;

// node for comp code and its translation
typedef struct compNode 
{
    char entry[4];
    char translation[8];
}
compNode;

// node for jump code and its translation
typedef struct jumpNode 
{
    char entry[4];
    char translation[4];
}
jumpNode;

/**
 * assemble: translates source assembly file into machine code.
 * returns true on success, else false;
 */
bool assemble(FILE* source, FILE* output);

/**
 *  addSym: add the symbol-translation pair to the start of the linked list beginning with head.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool addSym(const char* symbol, const char* translation, int line);

/**
 *  buildTables: builds the table for comp/jump codes and their translations.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool buildTables(void);

/**
 *  clearTables: frees the tables of comp/jump codes and their translations.
 */
void clearTables(void);

/** 
 *  decodeA: reads in an A instruction from source, and outputs the a-instruction to out, converted to binary.
 *  returns source line number, or -1 if error.
*/
int decodeA(FILE* source, FILE* output, int line);

/**
 *  writeComp: translates comp and outputs it to output.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool writeComp(char* comp, FILE* output);

/**
 *  writeJump: translates jump and outputs it to output.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool writeJump(char* jump, FILE* output);

/** 
 *  decodeC: reads in a C instruction from source (first char is c), and outputs the C-instruction to out, converted to binary.
 *  returns line number, or -1 on error.
*/
int decodeC(char c, FILE* source, FILE* output, int line);

/**
 *  loadLabels: populates the symbol dictionary with all of the labels in the file.
 *  returns true on success, else false;
 */
bool loadLabels(FILE* source);
```

**Assemble.c:**

```
/**
 *  file: assemble.c
 *
 *  assembler for the hack assembly language.
 *
 *  usage: assembler source output
 */

#include "assemble.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>    // bool type
#include <ctype.h>      // isspace(), isdigit()
#include <stdlib.h>     // atoi()
#include <string.h>     // strcpy(), strcmp(), strchr()


// head for symbol dictionary linked list
symNode* symHead;

// table for comp codes and their translations
compNode* compDict[COMP_TABLE_SIZE];

// table for jump codes and their translations
jumpNode* jumpDict[JUMP_TABLE_SIZE];

const char* compCodes[COMP_TABLE_SIZE] = {"0", "1", "-1", "D", "A", "!D", "!A", "-D", "-A",
                                            "D+1", "A+1", "D-1", "A-1", "D+A", "D-A", "A-D",
                                            "D&A", "D|A", "M", "!M", "-M", "M+1", "M-1", "D+M",
                                            "D-M", "M-D", "D&M", "D|M"};

const char* compTranslations[COMP_TABLE_SIZE] = {"0101010", "0111111", "0111010", "0001100",
                                                "0110000", "0001101", "0110001", "0001111",
                                                "0110011", "0011111", "0110111", "0001110",
                                                "0110010", "0000010", "0010011", "0010011",
                                                "0000000", "0010101", "1110000", "1110001",
                                                "1110011", "1110111", "1110010", "1000010",
                                                "1010011", "1000111", "1000000", "1010101"};

const char* jumpCodes[JUMP_TABLE_SIZE] = {"JGT", "JEQ", "JGE", "JLT", "JNE", "JLE", "JMP"};

const char* jumpTranslations[JUMP_TABLE_SIZE] = {"001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"};

/**
 *  addSym: add the symbol-translation pair to the start of the linked list beginning with head.
 *  returns true on success, else false;
 */
bool addSym(const char* symbol, const char* translation, int line)
{
    // construct the new node
    symNode* temp = malloc(sizeof(symNode));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): cannot malloc new symbol node.\n", line);
        return false;
    }
    strcpy(temp->symbol, symbol);
    strcpy(temp->translation, translation);

    if (symHead != NULL)    // list not empty
    {
        temp->next = symHead;
    }
    symHead = temp;
    return true;
}

/**
 *  buildTables: builds the table for comp/jump codes and their translations.
 */
bool buildTables(void)
{
    int i;

    // build comp table
    for (i = 0; i < COMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        compNode* temp = malloc(sizeof(compNode));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot create comp table\n");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(temp->entry, compCodes[i]);
        strcpy(temp->translation, compTranslations[i]);
        compDict[i] = temp;
    }

    // build jump table
    for (i = 0; i < JUMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        jumpNode* temp = malloc(sizeof(jumpNode));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot create jump table\n");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(temp->entry, jumpCodes[i]);
        strcpy(temp->translation, jumpTranslations[i]);
        jumpDict[i] = temp;
    }

    // load default register symbols into symbol table
    int v;
    int k;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        char* tempSym = malloc(4);
        if (tempSym == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot create register table\n");
            return false;
        }

        char* tempTran = malloc(17);
        if (tempTran == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot create register table\n");
            return false;
        }

        tempSym[0] = 'R';
        sprintf(tempSym+1, "%d", i);
        v = i;
        k = 0;
        for (j = 15; j >= 0; j--, k++)
        {
            tempTran[k] = '0' + ((v >> j) & 1);     
        }
        tempTran[k] = '\0';
        if (addSym(tempSym, tempTran, 0) == false)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot create register table\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 *  clearTables: frees the tables of comp/jump codes and their translations.
 */
void clearTables(void)
{
    // clear computations table
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < COMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        free(compDict[i++]);
    }

    // clear jump table
    for (i = 0; i < JUMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        free(jumpDict[i++]);
    }

    // clear symbol table
    symNode* pos = symHead;
    symNode* next;
    while (pos != NULL)
    {
        next = pos->next;
        free(pos);
        pos = next;
    }
}

/** 
 *  decodeA: reads in an A instruction from source, and outputs the a-instruction to out, converted to binary.
 *  returns source line number, or -1 if error.
*/
int decodeA(FILE* source, FILE* output, int line)
{
    static int varNum = 16;

    char* instruction = malloc(MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE + 1); //holds the number in the @instruction
    if (instruction == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (decodeA): cannot malloc instruction\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // read in the @ instruction
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    if ((c = fgetc(source)) && !isdigit(c))     // symbol
    {
        do
        {
            if (i > MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): symbol too large (max length %d chars)\n", line, MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE);
                return -1;
            }
            instruction[i++] = c;
        } while ((c = fgetc(source)) && !isspace(c) && c != EOF);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): expected value for A-instruction\n", line);
            return -1;
        }
        instruction[i] = '\0';

        // search table for instruction
        symNode* pos;
        for (pos = symHead; pos != NULL; pos = pos->next)
        {
            if (strcmp(instruction, pos->symbol) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(output, pos->translation);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pos == NULL)        // symbol not in table: add it!
        {
            char* tempTran = malloc(17);
            int k = 0;
            int j;
            int v = varNum;
            for (j = 15; j >= 0; j--, k++)
            {
                tempTran[k] = '0' + ((v >> j) & 1);     
            }
            tempTran[k] = '\0';
            addSym(instruction, tempTran, 0);
            varNum++;
            // output symbol
            fprintf(output, tempTran);
            fputc('\n', output);
            return line;
        }
    }
    if (isdigit(c))     // non-symbolic a-instruction
    {
        do
        {
            if (i > 4)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): integer too large\n", line);
                return -1;
            }
            instruction[i++] = c;
        } while ((c = fgetc(source)) && isdigit(c));

        if (i == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): expected value for A-instruction\n", line);
            return -1;
        }
        instruction[i] = '\0';

        // convert the @ instruction to int
        int v = atoi(instruction);
        free(instruction);
        if (v > MAX_A || v < 0) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): %d is an invalid integer\n", line, v);
            return -1;
        }

        // output the a-instruction converted to binary
        for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            fputc('0' + ((v >> i) & 1), output);
        }
    }

    // carry on reading until newline
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(source);
    }
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        fputc('\n', output);
        line++;
    }

    return line;
}

/**
 *  writeComp: translates comp and outputs it to output.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool writeComp(char* comp, FILE* output)
{
    // search computations for the comp
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < COMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(compDict[i]->entry, comp) == 0)
        {
            // found
            fprintf(output, compDict[i]->translation);
            return true;
        }
    }
    // not found
    printf("%s not found\n", comp);
    return false;
}

/**
 *  writeJump: translates jump and outputs it to output.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool writeJump(char* jump, FILE* output)
{
    // search jump table for the jump
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < JUMP_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(jumpDict[i]->entry, jump) == 0)
        {
            // found
            fprintf(output, jumpDict[i]->translation);
            return true;
        }
    }
    // not found
    return false;
}

/** 
 *  decodeC: reads in a C instruction from source (first char is c), and outputs the C-instruction to out, converted to binary.
 *  returns line number, or -1 on error.
*/
int decodeC(char c, FILE* source, FILE* output, int line)
{
    // C-instructions have three parts: dest, comp, and jump.
    char* dest = malloc(4);
    char* comp = malloc(4);
    char* jump = malloc(4);
    if (dest == NULL || dest == NULL || jump == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (line: %d): cannot malloc\n", line);
    }

    char* buffer = malloc(4);
    int i = 0;
    bool destIn = false;
    bool compIn = false;
    bool jumpIn = false;
    do
    {
        if (i > 3)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line: %d): invalid instruction\n", line);
        }
        else if (c == '=')  // buffer is dest
        {
            strcpy(dest, buffer);
            dest[i] = '\0';
            destIn = true;
            i = 0;
        }
        else if ((((c == '\n') || (c == '/') || c == EOF) && !compIn) || c == ';')  // buffer is comp
        {
            strcpy(comp, buffer);
            comp[i] = '\0';
            compIn = true;
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (((c == '\n') || (c == '/') || c == EOF) && compIn) // buffer is jump
        {
            strcpy(jump, buffer);
            jump[i] = '\0';
            jumpIn = true;
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c) && c != '/')
        {
            buffer[i++] = c;
        }
        if (c == '\n' || c == '/' || c == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (c = fgetc(source));

    // write C-instruction code (111)
    fprintf(output, "111");

    if (compIn) 
    {
        if (writeComp(comp, output) == false)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line: %d): cannot translate '%s'\n", line, comp);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // write default comp code
        fprintf(output, "111101010");
    }

    if (destIn)
    {
        if (strchr(dest, 'A') != NULL)
        {
            fputc('1', output);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc('0', output);
        }
        if (strchr(dest, 'D') != NULL)
        {
            fputc('1', output);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc('0', output);
        }
        if (strchr(dest, 'M') != NULL)
        {
            fputc('1', output);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc('0', output);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // write default dest
        fprintf(output, "000");
    }

    if (jumpIn)
    {
        if (writeJump(jump, output) == false)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (line: %d): cannot translate jump '%s'\n", line, jump);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // write default jump
        fprintf(output, "000");
    }

    free(dest);
    free(comp);
    free(jump);
    free(buffer);

    fputc('\n', output);
    line++;
    return line;
}

/**
 *  loadLabels: populates the symbol dictionary with all of the labels in the file.
 *  returns true on success, else false.
 */
bool loadLabels(FILE* source)
{
    char* tempLabel;
    char* tempTran;
    int line = 0;
    bool definingLabel = false; // are we defining a label?
    bool comment = false;   // are we in a comment?
    bool content = false; // is there content on the current line?
    bool addLabel = false; // should we add the current line to the label tag?
    int numLabels = 0;
    char c;
    int i = 0; // label pos
    while ((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '/')
        {
            comment = true;
        }
        else if (c == '(' && !comment)  // new label
        {
            if (definingLabel)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): cannot enter '(' in label name\n", line);
                return false;
            }
            definingLabel = true;

            tempLabel = malloc(MAX_SYMBOL_SIZE + 1);
            if (tempLabel == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): cannot malloc tempLabel\n", line);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (c == ')' && !comment)
        {
            if (!definingLabel)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): cannot enter ')' outside label\n", line);
                return false;
            }           
            definingLabel = false;

            // add to dict
            tempLabel[i] = '\0';
            i = 0;
            addSym(tempLabel, "", line);
            addLabel = true;
            numLabels++;
        }
        else if (definingLabel && !comment)
        {
            if (isspace(c))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error (line %d): cannot enter whitespace in label name\n", line);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                tempLabel[i++] = c;
            }
        }
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            comment = false;
            if (content)
            {
                line++;
            }
            content = false;
        }
        else if (!isspace(c) && !comment && !definingLabel && c != ')')
        {
            content = true;
            if (addLabel)
            {
                tempTran = malloc(17);
                int v = line;
                int k = 0;
                int j;
                for (j = 15; j >= 0; j--, k++)
                {
                    tempTran[k] = '0' + ((v >> j) & 1);     
                }
                tempTran[k] = '\0';

                for (symNode* pos = symHead; numLabels > 0; numLabels--)
                {
                    strcpy(pos->translation, tempTran);
                    pos = pos->next;
                }
                addLabel = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (addLabel)
    {
        tempTran = malloc(17);
        int v = line;
        int k = 0;
        int j;
        for (j = 15; j >= 0; j--, k++)
        {
            tempTran[k] = '0' + ((v >> j) & 1);     
        }
        tempTran[k] = '\0';

        for (symNode* pos = symHead; numLabels > 0; numLabels--)
        {
            strcpy(pos->translation, tempTran);
            pos = pos->next;
        }
    }

    // rewind the file
    fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return true;
}


bool assemble(FILE* source, FILE* output)
{
    // build translation tables
    if (buildTables() == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Terminating program due to error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (loadLabels(source) == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Terminating program due to error\n"); 
        return 1;
    }

    // main read loop
    char c;
    bool comment = false;   // are we in a comment?
    bool label = false;     // are we in a label?
    int line = 1;   // source line number
    while ((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '/')
        {
            comment = true;
        }
        else if (c == '\n')
        {
            line++;
            comment = false;    // newline breaks comments
        }
        else if (c == '(')
        {
            label = true;
        }
        else if (c == ')')
        {
            label = false;
        }
        else if (label)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (isspace(c))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (comment) 
        {
            continue;   // skip comments
        }
        else if (c == '@')  // A-INSTRUCTION
        {
            line = decodeA(source, output, line);
        }
        else                // C-INSTRUCTION (or invalid)
        {
            line = decodeC(c, source, output, line);
        }
        if (line == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Terminating assembly due to error\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // clear translation tables
    clearTables();

    fclose(source);
    fclose(output);

    printf("Assembly successful\n");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: [Stack Exchange policy prohibits the deletion of questions with upvoted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/148099). Furthermore, [self-vandalism is not an acceptable workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209436/148099).

Answer (score 1):

## Linear searches

I noticed that there are several places where you search through your various tables using linear searches.  It would be easy to sort your tables and add a search function that uses a binary search instead.

Currently your `symHead` points to a linked list of symbols, but you could modify that to be an array instead (just resize as needed).  Then you could use a binary search on it.

## Trie

Depending on your speed requirements, you could even go a step further and build a trie for your symbol table.  Searches and symbol additions would be faster using a trie than using a sorted array.

However, you should only do this if you expect large symbol tables and if execution time is a major concern.  For small input files, I doubt that using a trie will make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering whether or not to sort -- I wasn't sure whether it was worth O(n lg n) time to sort the array every time you add a symbol just to gain O(lg n) speed on binary search rather than O(n). I guess it is worth it, since you add symbols far less than you search them. I'll get on it! :D